# Apache connections limit

Tags: php, apache

My hosting says that apache connections limit is 30. I don't whether its enough or not for an average site with 100 visitors per day. I want to know what are the things I should adapt for this limit while coding the site. Mostly I 'll use php sessions and little ajax . I want to know if there any precautions and recommended practices (if any) to avoid hitting this limit.
Thank you.

Comment: i wouldn't worry, it would be a very poor host that couldn't support a site of that size.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will be using AJAX, I can't stress this enough...**Do not long poll with Apache!** It will hold your connections open and effectively perform a DOS(Denial of Service) on your own site.

Other than that, minimize the time it takes between when Apache receives a request to when it outputs and closes. The big blinking neon sign here is to use **caching**. Whether it is file based caching or something like Memcached or APC, this *can* drastically reduce the time Apache holds a connection open.

Answer (score 1):

Taken by itself, the statement "apache connections limit is 30" doesn't actually mean much -- Apache configuration can be fairly involved and there are a lot of numbers/parameters. But if we assume that what this really means is '[MaxClients](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients) is 30', then what you need to know is that you have a limit of 30 simultaneous connections. However, connection 31 isn't rejected -- it should just be queued until there's a thread available to respond to the request.  There's a lot of specifics according to the config, etc, but I doubt you need to worry much.

Answer (score 0):

This means there are 30 possible concurrent connections possible, if you have 100 visitors per day, it's very unlikely to have about a third at the same time.
As you are growing with your site I'd recommend you another server/hoster.

But as if you don't make long running persistent connections and high frequent AJAX call all the time, this should be enough.

Comment: Performing post and get requests by jquery in response to events(clicking,etc) count as persistent connections? because I heard that ajax calls will keep the connections open

Comment: No all requests in HTTP are short living. To keep persistent connections without getting a timeout you have to do more requests to keep it alive. With persistent I meant Streams for example

Answer (score 0):

Connection limit is most probably simultaneous requests. So if you're only at the development stage, that is fine. But as for once it has launched, that is a different story. If your expected traffic is only about 100 visitors a day, then you will most probably be fine. I would however recommend to change your VPS host if it is anything over that, as if the server is turning away visitors, then it is not good for business.

But in all honesty you're better off developing locally for now to save your bandwidth for actual visitors, as from your description you don't seem to be using anything that requires a live site.